# Angular: Can I ensure that my logging module gets configured before $exceptionHandler under normal circumstances?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, raygun

I'm writing an error-logging module to add Raygun logging to an AngularJS application.  The [standard method](https://raygun.io/blog/2014/06/track-angular-js-exceptions-automatically/) is to register a decorator for `$exceptionHandler` like so:

```
$provide.decorator("$exceptionHandler", ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
    return function (exception, cause) {
      Raygun.send(exception);
      $delegate(exception, cause);
    }
  }])
```

However, this has an order dependence in that the decorator must be installed before the DI framework first loads `$exceptionHandler`.  If I'm wrapping this code in a module, the order dependence is even less obvious, and it's easy for the client to initialize things in the wrong order and have no idea why `Raygun.send` isn't getting called.  (I was that client for a day and a half.  In my defense, this is my first experience with Angular.)

I'd like to persuade Angular's DI framework to load my error-logging module before `$exceptionHandler`, with the obvious caveat that I'm hosed if any exceptions are thrown really early in bootstrapping.  I thought of trying to register my module as a dependency of `$exceptionHandler`, but haven't been able to figure out how to do that yet -- also, it's not actually true that `$exceptionHandler` depends upon my code.  Is there an idiomatic way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Angular instantiates `$exceptionHandler` and all other `ng-` services during its own config phase, during its own `ng` module instantiation. Simply move your code to a config of the `ng` module:

```
angular.module('ng')
.config(['$provide', function($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$exceptionHandler', ['$delegate', function($delegate) {
        return function (exception, cause) {
            Raygun.send(exception);
            $delegate(exception, cause);
        }
    }]);
}]);
```

This configuration will be placed in the queue immediately after `$exceptionHandler` gets instantiated.

However, config/run errors are *not* delegated to `$exceptionHandler` or any angular logger, they are simply uncaught, propagating to the end of the stack. You can capture these exceptions, but you must [manually bootstrap angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap#manual-initialization). Remove the ng-app attribute, and instead run this code:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    try {
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['yourModule']);
    } catch (exception) {
        Raygun.send(exception);
        throw exception;
    }
});
```

With both errors caught passing though the `$exceptionHandler` and caught during bootstrapping, there shouldn't be an error that doesn't get reported.

Example plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/XsiMNA7GIbHzXyjEioxy?p=preview
Open your console and uncomment one of the errors in script.js on line 9 or 15. You should see angular's regular error handling as well as a dummy Raygun.send logging warnings to the console.